# Dynamic AutoComplete

Tags: codenameone

When I type a location starting with 'W', the related locations are listed below. But if I erase the already typed location and then type in a different one starting with 'L', then the list shows the previously listed options for the old location first(locations starting with 'W') then the options related to new location are listed.

Because of this the autocomplete list displays the locations starting with 'W' and then the locations starting with 'L',both.
I also tried placing options.removeAll(); as first statement in the filter method.

```
AutoCompleteTextField ac = new AutoCompleteTextField(options) {
protected boolean filter(String add) {
             options.removeAll();
             if(add.length() == 0) {


                 return false;
             }
             String[] l = searchLocations(add);
             if(l == null || l.length == 0) {
                 return false;
             }


             for(String s : l) {
                 options.addItem(s);
             }
             return true;
         }
     };
    //ac.setMinimumElementsShownInPopup(1);

     ac.setMinimumLength(1);
     Container c = stateMachine.findContainer(form);
     AutoCompleteTextField oldac = (AutoCompleteTextField) stateMachine.findAddress(c);
     c.replace(oldac, ac, null);
```

Is there a way to rectify this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this live sample](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/dynamic-autocomplete.html), this issue doesn't occur here so I'm guessing the problem with the preexisting results is related to the way you modified the the model.